# OData Gateway - HTTP Open failed: PLUGIN_NOT_ACTIVE

Tags: sap-gateway

When I am trying to run SAP oData service I am seeing below popup message. Please help me how to activate this plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to maintain port number 80000 for HTTP in SMICM Tcode.